# Monitor the "active state" of Biztalk send port service instance

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013

Team,

My biztalk send port instance gets hung and stays in the active state for longer periods of time. I would like to monitor that send port active instance with the help of C#. 
I intend to run a code which will check if the send port(passed as a parameter) is still in a running state or not. Can anyone help me with that piece of code ?

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong problem.  Why is the Send Port in an active state for long periods to begin with.  What Adapter is it using?

Comment: This was just a one off incident but which caused a huge loss and we would like to avert this in future. This uses a SFTP adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WMI [MSBTS_ServiceInstance.ServiceStatus Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561123.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
public static int GetRunningServiceInstanceCount()
{
    int countofServiceInstances = 0;
    try
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\MicrosoftBizTalkServer", "SELECT * FROM MSBTS_ServiceInstance WHERE ServiceStatus = 1 or ServiceStatus = 2");
        countofServiceInstances = searcher.Get().Count;
        return countofServiceInstances;
    }
    catch (ManagementException exWmi)
    {
        throw new System.Exception("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + exWmi.Message);
    }
}
```

To get to your actual problem: The SFTP adapter in BizTalk 2016 has a [great way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/sftp-adapter#use-a-newer-winscp-version) of using the most recent version of the FTP code. This might solve stability issues.

Assuming from your BizTalk 2013 tag, you're probably not using the 2016 version, in that case double check you are at least at [CU3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3088676/cumulative-update-package-3-for-microsoft-biztalk-server-2013) since that one solves a few critical SFTP bugs.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Can i pass the name of a specific send port name within this query? How do you do that ? Will that be SELECT * FROM MSBTS_ServiceInstance WHERE ServiceStatus = 1 or ServiceStatus = 2 and name like %portname%

Comment: I suggest you try this code out and debug what you get in the 'searcher' object. I don't think portname is going to work, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578129.aspx for what you can get from the object.

Comment: I am trying to use the powershell but i do not know as to how to substitute the send port name in the fiter. Can you help me?                       [ARRAY]$active = get-wmiobject MSBTS_ServiceInstance -namespace 'root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer' -filter '(ServiceStatus = 2) and how to search by name' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 

 Write-Host "Active Instances:" $active.Count